# Best way to get csv data from sting in C# to records in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, csv

I want to get a `.csv` data from asp.net C# postback into a table as individual records and keep the order as a priority listing.

```
Value = 'first,2,end'
```

should be inserted into the SQL Server table in that order.

The source table has additional columns that can be hard coded in the stored procedure.

I have a `Split` function that returns a table variable but am not able to figure out how to get the values returned into the source table along with ancillary data.

My table is this:

```
Id  int
PositionId  int
Name    varchar
ListOrder   int
Score   int
ScoreNotes  nvarchar
isrequired  int
```

My SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO Skills (PositionId, Name, ListOrder, Score, ScoreNotes, isrequired) 
   SELECT
       @PositionId,
       (select positionVal, skill from dbo.fn_split ('first,sec,last', ',') ),
       null,
       null,
       @isrequired)
```

Comment: Relational databases don't have a real concept of record order. Usually an  unordered view of the table will show records in the order they were inserted. However, this is just a coincidence, because this order tends to match autoincrement/identity primary keys and tends to match the page order on disk. It just happens to be efficient. However, there are all kinds of conditions that can make a database change this implicit order when showing records. If you care about the order, you **must** have a column in the table that indicates what the order should be.

Comment: Unless your sql server version is very old (2005 or less), You should use a table valued parameter and do the split string in your c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to change your sql to be :

```
    create procedure myproc
         @myvalue varchar(max),
         @positionid int,
         @isrequired int
    as

    INSERT INTO Skills (PositionId,Name,ListOrder,Score,ScoreNotes,isrequired)        
           (select @PositionId,positionVal, skill, null, null, @isrequired 
     from dbo.fn_split (@myvalue, ',') )

    GO
```